# z3 variable naming standards

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, z3

Is it that z3 doesn't allow variables starting with

```
    __*
```

After I run the following code in python

```
    __a = BitVec('__a', 3)
```

Program terminates due to some error but doesn't give the reason of termination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Z3 at [rise4fun.com](http://rise4fun.com/z3py). The online tool uses code "sanitizer". The idea is to prevent attacks to the rise4fun website. For example, it will block `import` statements, and names starting with `__`. The sanitizer is conservative, and blocks several harmless scripts. 
If you execute Z3 on your machine, your script will work. I just tried the following simple one:

```py
   from z3 import *
   __a = BitVec('__a', 3)
   print a
```

BTW, the following variation works at rise4fun (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/jNnZ)):

```py
   _a = BitVec('__a', 3)
   print a
```